# Java Data-structures hashtable

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

How can I solve this error (the error is in bold):
What I need to do is hash the elements when I copy them to the temp array

---

```
public class LinearProbingHashTable<E> {
    private Entry[] hashArray;
    private Entry defunct;

    public LinearProbingHashTable(int size) {
        hashArray = new Entry[size];
        defunct = new Entry(-1, null);
    }

    public int hashFunc(int key) {
        return key % hashArray.length;
    }

    private void expand(int newCapacity) {
        Entry<E> temp[];
        temp = new Entry[newCapacity];
        // add you code here
        for( int i=0; i< hashArray.length; i++) {
            int index = **hashFunc**(hashArray[i]);
            while(**temp[index]!=0**) {
                index = (index+1)% temp.length;
            }
            temp[index]=hashArray[i];
        }
        hashArray = temp;
    }

    // INCLUDED FOR TESTING
    public int getCapacity() {
        return hashArray.length;
    }

    public class Entry<E> {
        private int key;
        private E data;

        public Entry(int k, E d) {
            key = k;
            data = d;
        }

        public int getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public E getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void display() {
            System.out.print(key + ":");
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }

}
```

I need to fix the bold error but I couldn't.
The error I get is: **The method hashFunc(int) in the type LinearProbingHashTable is not applicable for the arguments (LinearProbingHashTable.Entry)**
And the error for the second line is: **Incompatible operand types LinearProbingHashTable.Entry and int**

Comment: "the error is in bold" <- This doesn't work. You can't make formatted code bold. Please just tell us what line is giving an error and what the exact error message you are getting is.

Comment: The error is between /**/. Here exactly: int index = /**/hashFunc/**/(hashArray[i]);
            while(/**/temp[index]!=0/**/)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Already edited

Answer (score 2):

The errors you are getting are because you are passing an `Entry` object into a method that expects an `int`, and because you try to compare an `Entry` object with an `int`.

Your class `Entry` and the objects of it are not `int` objects and can't be used like one. But your class has an int field `private int key` that I would guess you probably meant to use in both cases.

So you need to change your code to use that field by using the getter of your class:

change

```
int index = hashFunc(hashArray[i]);
```

to

```
int index = hashFunc(hashArray[i].getKey());
```

and change

```
while(temp[index]!=0)
```

to

```
while(temp[index].getKey() != 0)
```

That will make your code syntactically correct. I can't say anything about whether it will be logically correct as I haven't tested that aspect.

Comment: I am still getting this error **Cannot invoke "LinearProbingHashTable$Entry.getKey()" because "temp[index]" is null**